# What is causing my program to bog down when writing to XSSF Workbook?

Tags: java, performance, optimization, xssf

Maybe "writing" wasn't the correct word since in this function, I am just setting the cells and then writing afterwards.

I have a function that I have pin pointed to be the cause of it bogging down. When it gets to this function, it spends over 10 minutes here before I just terminate it.
This is the function that I am passing an `output_wb` to:

```
private static void buildRowsByListOfRows(int sheetNumber, ArrayList<Row> sheet, Workbook wb) {
    Sheet worksheet = wb.getSheetAt(sheetNumber);
    int lastRow;
    Row row;
    String cell_value;
    Cell cell;
    int x = 0;
    System.out.println("Size of array list: " + sheet.size());
    for (Row my_row : sheet) {
        try {
            lastRow = worksheet.getLastRowNum();
            row = worksheet.createRow(++lastRow);

            for (int i = 0; i < my_row.getLastCellNum(); i++) {
                cell_value = getCellContentAsString(my_row.getCell(i, Row.MissingCellPolicy.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK));
                cell = row.createCell(i);
                cell.setCellValue(cell_value);
                System.out.println("setting row #: " + x + "with value =>" + cell_value);
            }
            x++;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("SOMETHING WENT WRONG");
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

The size of the `ArrayList` is `73,835`. It starts off running pretty fast then it gets to around row `20,000` and it then you can see the print statements in the loop getting spread out further and further apart. Each row has `70` columns.

Is this function really written that poorly or is something else going on?
What can I do to optimize this?

I create the output workbook like this if this matters:

```
// Create output file with the required sheets 
createOutputXLSFile(output_filename_path);
XSSFWorkbook output_wb = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(output_filename_path));
```

And the `createOutputXLSFile()` looks like this:

```
private static void createOutputXLSFile(String output_filename_path) throws FileNotFoundException {
    try {
        // Directory path where the xls file will be created
        // Create object of FileOutputStream
        FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(output_filename_path);
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
        wb.createSheet("Removed records"); 
        wb.createSheet("Added records"); 
        wb.createSheet("Updated records"); 

        // Build the Excel File
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        wb.write(outputStream);
        outputStream.writeTo(fout);
        outputStream.close();
        fout.close();
        wb.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

```
    private static String getCellContentAsString(Cell cell) {
        DataFormatter fmt = new DataFormatter();
        String data = null;
        if (cell.getCellType() == CellType.STRING) {
            data = String.valueOf(cell.getStringCellValue());
        } else if (cell.getCellType() == CellType.NUMERIC) {
            data = String.valueOf(fmt.formatCellValue(cell));
        } else if (cell.getCellType() == CellType.BOOLEAN) {
            data = String.valueOf(fmt.formatCellValue(cell));
        } else if (cell.getCellType() == CellType.ERROR) {
            data = String.valueOf(cell.getErrorCellValue());
        } else if (cell.getCellType() == CellType.BLANK) {
            data = String.valueOf(cell.getStringCellValue());
        } else if (cell.getCellType() == CellType._NONE) {
            data = String.valueOf(cell.getStringCellValue());
        }
        return data;
    }
```

Update #1- Seems to be happening here. If I comment out all 3 lines then it finishes:

```
    cell_value = getCellContentAsString(my_row.getCell(i, Row.MissingCellPolicy.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK));
    cell = row.createCell(i);
    cell.setCellValue(cell_value);
```

Update #2 - If I comment out these two lines, then the loop finishes as expected:

```
    cell = row.createCell(i); // The problem
    cell.setCellValue(cell_value);
```

So now I know the problem is the `row.createCell(i)` but why? How can I optimize this?

Comment: (1) Is the output file on a filesystem that is local to the machine where the code is running? (2) what version of apache poi are you using?

Comment: Yes, everything is local and version `5.0.0`

Comment: Have you tried committing every 1000 rows or so?

Comment: No I haven't. Do you mean writing `output_wb.write(fo_output_file);` inside my loop somewhere or how do you mean?

Comment: No. `wb.commit();`.

Comment: What does that do?

Comment: I would hope that the implementation writes unwritten cells to the output file and release resources that are more expensive to release if the number of unwritten changes is larger than what some other developer anticipated.

Comment: Ah, I tried, but it says the method `commit() is undefined for the type Workbook`

Comment: Without debugging apache poi, my best suggestion, since it looks like buildRowsByListOfRows appends rows to a sheet, is to (a) open, (b) append, (c) close the workbook for 1000 rows or so and see if that fixes the problem. I hate that suggestion because the writing of the workbook at close (in each iteration) sounds like a ramp. But if it drastically reduces response time, then you can try to optimize the "close" later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally managed to resolve this issue. Turns out that using `XSSF` to write is just too slow if the files are large. So I converted the `XSSF` output workbook to an `SXSSFWorkbook`. To do that I just passed in my already existing `XSSFWorkbook` into `SXSSFWorkbook` like this :

```
        // Create output file with the required sheets 
        createOutputXLSFile(output_filename_path);
        XSSFWorkbook output_wb_temp = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(output_filename_path));
        SXSSFWorkbook output_wb = new SXSSFWorkbook(output_wb_temp);
```

The rest of the code works as is.